# Retrieving a documents field value from Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am trying to assign the field artName to my "documents" but for some reason the documents.push() does not want to add doc.artName, it does populate the id and url and when I console.log doc.data() it does show artName with the assigned value, any help is greatly appreciated.

My code is:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config';

const useFirestore = (collection) => {
    const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = projectFirestore.collection(collection)
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot((snap) => {
            let documents = [];
            snap.forEach(doc => {
                documents.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id, artName: doc.artName })
            });
            setDocs(documents);
        });

        return () => unsub();

    }, [collection])

    return { docs };
}

export default useFirestore;
```

Comment: Hello, if my answer was useful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon. [What should I do when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) else feel free to ask further queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `artName` field present in the document itself? Then you don't explicitly add that to your object. The `doc.data()` has it all. You only need to add the `id` yourself.

```
snap.forEach(doc => {
  documents.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
});
```

This should do it. The problem is you are trying to add `artName` with `doc.artName` as the value which is `undefined`. `doc.data().artName` would have worked but you just don't need to do that.